# Can't find .lnk shortcuts Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, search

I have many .lnk shortcuts that I use on a daily basis, including multiple different users on Chrome and start locations for CMD. When I search their names on windows search (win+s), the shortcuts show up, but when I use any third party search applications (such as Cerebro, Wox, etc.), I can't find them. Why is this?

It's worth noting that I have only had this problem after switching to a new windows 10 laptop, on my old one .lnk files worked fine with Cerebro and Wox.

Comment: You can't find `.lnk` files with a glob search?

Comment: I don't believe I can

Comment: Which version of Windows was on your previous computer?

Comment: Also windows 10

Comment: I'm not familiar with Cerebro & Wox, but the difference between the two computers might be in their options. I use the excellent [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) and have no problem searching for `*.lnk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with onedrive. For some reason, all applications in my desktop folder were actually under Users\user\onedrive\Desktop, while the search applications only searched Users\user\Desktop. I guess my new windows 10 installation had different onedrive settings.